# How to return to search page imitating back button in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts, back, struts-tags

I have a Struts 2 application. The first page is a Search page which then goes to an Edit page by clicking on individual elements on the Search page.

My problem is once in Edit page, users can save changes and do whatever they want but I would like to give them a back link to take them to the search page taking them to same result search *not* to the main search page alone.

Basically I want the link to remember the actual search result page.

Tried

```
<s:a href="/search/search.action">Search page</s:a>
```

renders the initial search page with no result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state from the Search page in the `session`, and pass the reference to it via the parameter of the action.

Using that parameter value you could retrieve the state back and reinitialize the action when you give it a back link.

It's easily done if you save a request URL of the Search page and redirect back to it on `"back"` redirect result by supplying the URL as a parameter to it.

Comment: What's not clear? You have also probably not only save the query string but the submitted fields too.